# How to get templated starter database driven forms generated in C# winforms SQL Server using some RAD tool or Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, code-generation

I hope I got all that in this question title. Let me explain. We are starting on small desktop app that will snowball into a big app with many forms. The database is SQL Server. It will have classic stored procs/functions performing classic CRUD functions. Given a table or stored proc in SQL Server what is the quickest way to create a form with all the hooks to maintain a table.

For e.g. lets assume I have table like this (most code below is pseudo code)

```
Table Employee 
{
      Name varchar(30)
      DOB Datetime
      Address varchar(100)
}
```

From this as **source** I want to create my **Target** which is form with 3 labels and 3 textboxes with add delete modify buttons (or OK button to add if not exists or modify if exists)

```
 Name: TextBox
 DOB:  TextBox or Datetime picker 
 Address: Textbox

  OK   DELETE   CLOSE
```

The code generation tool or technique that will be used should generate the correct db hooks (create SQL parameters, `SqlCommand`, execute sql.. basic try catch etc. Is there any open source tool to do this ? Some trick or templated approach via VS 2010 ? Worst case any third party tool ? thank you

Comment: There aer quite a few commercial toolkits for this - e.g. [IronSpeed](http://www.ironspeed.com/) or [Haystack](http://www.codehaystack.com/) - not cheap, but powerful. I don't know of any really cheap or free tools like this (it does take a lot of work to get something like that up and running, and those developers want to earn money, too....)

Comment: Another possibility - Microsoft Lightswitch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at http://nettiers.com ?

It is basically a set of templates (not [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)) that lets you generate most of the layers you want of an 
application.

I like it because it is very easy to extend what is generated and to build incremental apps with it, based on the database:
first iteration : choose your first X tables, generate any layer you like (winform or asp.net, DAL, stored procedures for CRUD, entities, ...), then extend what is generated using the partial classes provided or the base classes
second iteration : add X tables to your selection, regenerate, take advantage of all your customization.

The only down side of nettiers is that you need to have a licence of [codesmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) to execute the templates, and it cost 100$.

Comment: First time i am seeing an open source app that is dependent on a commercial app. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

There is DBEXform designer tool to create database forms reports and applications for Windows.

Applications are execute on .Net 3.5 environment.

Latist version of DBEXform could be downloaded from http://www.willmansoft.com

:JW

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.metadrone.com](http://www.metadrone.com)

It's a new tool, not many templates created for it yet.
But it's easy to use to create your own templates to make generated stored procedures and forms to suit your own style of coding.